# Unable to uninstall msipackage when application is installed in different language other than English

Tags: .net, wix

Issue: When the application is installed in different language (ex: Spanish) using managed bootstrapper with custom UI, It will install without any errors. But when we try to uninstall the same setup file, it will uninstall only the bundle , but not MSI Package.

We have created the MSI and supported localization by embedding the TRANSFORMs (.mst file).

When we install via MSI without custom bootstrapper, install and uninstall both works fine for multi languages, but same thing does not work when we embed MSI in custom bootstrapper.

Answer (score 0):

There is an open feature request for bundles to support multi-instance MsiPackages: https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/6472.

Comment: Thank you Sean for the response. We are currently using Wix v3.11.2 with custom bootstrapper.                                                                                                                  What we have noticed was, this works fine when installer is built using standard  bootstrapper, but not with custom bootstrapper. we are getting the following error code:                 
Unable to register source directory, reason: 0x80070645.